# Regex or Other Method to Parse Obj-C Method Declaration

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I have an Objective-C method of the form:

```
"hideAlertWithBundleId:(NSString *)bundleId uuid:(NSString *)uuid"
```

but it could also be written out in a form like this:

```
"hideAlertWithBundleId:   (NSString *)  bundleId         uuid: (NSString *) uuid"
```

and I want to extract:

```
["hideAlertWithBundleId:(NSString *)bundleId", "uuid:(NSString *)uuid"]
```

I've had trouble using pure Python and regex to achieve this, but I know it is possible.

Keep in mind, the values in the parenthesis can be *anything*. So, I may also have to parse:

```
"findImageWithKey:(id)arg1 inGroup:(id)arg2 andInfo:(img*)arg3"
```

It can be assumed that there are no newline characters in the string. The solution should work for a method with any number of arguments.

Comment: This is probably not a job for regexes. I'm not familiar with Objective-C, but I suspect doing this correctly requires being able to match parentheses (or at least count them). Regexes can't do that, or at least, they can't without much more powerful extensions than Python's `re` module has.

Comment: If the string were like your first line (no extra spaces), what rule would tell you where the string were to be split; i.e. why on the space between `"bundleId"` and `"uuid:"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not so familiar with Objective-C but if I'm understing the issue properly, how about:

```
import re
for str in ["hideAlertWithBundleId:(NSString *)bundleId uuid:(NSString *)uuid",
    "hideAlertWithBundleId:   (NSString *)  bundleId         uuid: (NSString *) uuid",
    "-(BOOL)findImageWithKey:(id)arg1 inGroup:(id)arg2 andInfo:(img*)arg3"]:
    result = re.findall(r'((?:-\s*\(\w+\)\s*)?\w+)\s*:\s*(\(\w+\s*\*?\))\s*(\w+)', str)
    result2 = [i[0] + ":" + i[1] + i[2] for i in result]
    print(result2)
```

Result:

```
['hideAlertWithBundleId:(NSString *)bundleId', 'uuid:(NSString *)uuid']
['hideAlertWithBundleId:(NSString *)bundleId', 'uuid:(NSString *)uuid']
['-(BOOL)findImageWithKey:(id)arg1', 'inGroup:(id)arg2', 'andInfo:(img*)arg3']
```

Comment: thank you, but I probably should have been more specific ... the argument type (in the parenthesis) can be basically anything, not only "NSString *" so this fails for an example like:

```"findImageWithKey:(id)arg1 inGroup:(id)arg2 andInfo:(img*)arg3"```

Comment: @YulkyTulky thank you for the prompt feedback. I've tweaked the regex based on your update. I'm not aware of the all types Objective-C declarations and if I need more modifications, please let me know.

Comment: @YulkyTulky good to know it's working. If we need additional modifications, please let me know.